# Servlet java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, servlets, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification from servlet to android using FCM. Here is my code.

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    try{
        String registrationToken = "Key";

     // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("score", "850")
                .setTopic("Topic")
                //.putData("time", "now")
                .setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        String respon = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        // Response is a message ID string.
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + respon);            
    }
    catch(FirebaseMessagingException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it, it shows me this error
[image]

Comment: Can you show how you initialize FirebaseApp?

Answer (score 2):

You must follow the steps below to fix the error:

1. Make sure FirebaseApp.initializeApp() is called.
2. If you not set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable in the environment, you need build StorageOptions. Example:

   ```
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
            new FileInputStream("{path-to-your-file}/service-account-file.json"))
            .createScoped(List.of("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
   ```
3. If you use environment variable look this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#java